# NSDrawer causes crash when added to App Window

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, appkit

I'm trying to programmatically add an `NSDrawer` to my app's main window (which also has an `NSOutlineView`which was setup in IB):

Ivar:

```
var dd: NSDrawer? = nil
```

Then, when a disclosure triangle button is clicked:

```
if dd == nil {
            var drawer_rect = NSInsetRect(self.window.frame, 30, 30).size
            drawer_rect.height = 150
            dd = NSDrawer.init(contentSize: drawer_rect, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
            dd!.contentView = self.status_scroll
            dd!.parentWindow = self.window
        }
```

So when the user tries to 'disclose' the drawer, the above code creates an `NSDrawer` and then displays it. It all works fine but Xcode dumps the following out as the `parentWindow` is set:

```
[General] ERROR: Setting <NSOutlineView: 0x100f0b9b0> as the first responder for window <NSDrawerWindow: 0x100fc8900>, but it is in a different window (<NSWindow: 0x6080001e0600>)! This would eventually crash when the view is freed. The first responder will be set to nil.
(
    0   AppKit                              0x00007fff9fc289cf -[NSWindow _validateFirstResponder:] + 557
    1   AppKit                              0x00007fff9f3a374c -[NSWindow _setFirstResponder:] + 31
    2   AppKit                              0x00007fff9f90c35b -[NSDrawerWindow _setParentWindow:] + 64
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff9f90b666 -[NSDrawer(DrawerInternals) _doSetParentWindow:] + 382
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff9f907786 -[NSDrawer setParentWindow:] + 78
```

Comment out the setting of the parentWindow and nothing gets dumped to the console.

Comment: `NSDrawer` is deprecated, right?

Comment: Well, look at that. Yes it is; If I search for the docs through Google I can see that. On the Xcode embedded documentation, though, there's no mention of it! I never gave it a second though when I was updating my App to Swift. Arguably, you've answered my question.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I have made my comment as answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSDrawer` is deprecated as per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdrawer). You should consider a different design. If you still use `NSDrawer`, you may face such issues.

Comment: I've submitted a report in Bug Reporter.